# How to use random.choices variable in a conditional statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use a randomly selected item from a list in an IF statement, my program is not recognise the `Newchoice` variable even when I set its odds to appear 100% of the time (`odds = [100, 0, 0]`)

Here is my current code:

```py
import random

Subjects = ["Retro", "Technology", "Sport"]
odds = [100, 0, 0]

Newchoice = random.choices(Subjects, odds, k=1)
print(Newchoice)

if Newchoice == "Retro":
    print("Success")
```

I expect the output show:

```py
['Retro']
Success
```

But I am getting simply:

```py
['Retro']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`random.choices` returns a list hence `NewChoice` refers to a list (containing string "Retro"), but you're comparing to the string "Retro".

You can either do list comparison:

```
if Newchoice == ["Retro"]:
```

or string comparison by getting the first (and only as `k=1`) element:

```
if Newchoice[0] == "Retro":
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because random.choices returns a list, and you're comparing it to string.
["Retro"] != "retro". Take the first (and only) element from the list and it'll work.

```
Newchoice = random.choices(Subjects, odds, k=1)[0]
```